# Forms - Show a hidden field by selecting an option in the select tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, hiddenfield

Ok so, I have this select area in my form and also a hidden field called "insert product number". What I want to do is: if the user selects the "product" option, the hidden field will show right below the selection field. How can I do that? Thanks!

```
    <select>
      <option>Jobs</option>
      <option>Products</option>
      <option>Other</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  <select id="types">
  <option value="1">Jobs</option>
  <option value="2">Products</option>
  <option value="3">Other</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="products" placeholder="Insert product number" style="display:none"/>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#types").change(function(){

  var type = $(this).val();

   if(type  == "2"){
        $("#products").show();
      }else{
        $("#products").hide();
      }
});

});

</script>
```

**Note:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

add jquery library

Comment: I found it very easy to understand since I am a newbie on JS! Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

you need yo check the selected value of select box.

```
<select id="ddlSelect">
      <option>Jobs</option>
      <option>Products</option>
      <option>Other</option>
    </select>
<input type="text" id="hdnPro" value="product" style='display:none'/>

$('#ddlSelect').on('change',function(){
   if($(this).val() == 'Products'){
        $('#hdnPro').show();
      }else{
        $('#hdnPro').hide();
      }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/0nmhjmk4/)**

Comment: Thank you very much for your time!! I mixed this with the other guy's code :D